# return only the longer in the same unit with same reference

Tags: javascript

We want to remove array item if in the same unit there is equal references and when there is such condition only include the item with more duration:

```
const array = [
  
  {
    reference: 'Tet our mission not here',
    duration: { start: '2:33.213', end: '2:35.871' },
    unit: 21,
  },
  
  {
    reference: 'Tet our mission',
    duration: { start: '2:33.213', end: '2:35.871' },
    unit: 22,
  },
  {
    reference: 'we built the Tet our mission control',
    duration: { start: '2:10.000', end: '2:40.403' },
    unit: 23,
  },
  
  {
    reference: 'we built the Tet our mission control',
    duration: { start: '2:40.000', end: '2:40.403' },
    unit: 23,
  },
  
  {
    reference: 'we built the Tet',
    duration: { start: '2:37.345', end: '2:38.500' },
    unit: 23,
  },
  {
    reference: 'we built the Tet our mission control',
    duration: { start: '2:30.000', end: '2:40.403' },
    unit: 23,
  }
  
];
```

In the following code we can only include one of the each unit items with longest duration but we want to check if there is same reference right?

Please compare the below result with desired output at the end of the page.

```js
     const array = [

  {
    reference: 'Tet our mission not here',
    duration: {
      start: '2:33.213',
      end: '2:35.871'
    },
    unit: 21,
  },

  {
    reference: 'Tet our mission',
    duration: {
      start: '2:33.213',
      end: '2:35.871'
    },
    unit: 22,
  },
  {
    reference: 'we built the Tet our mission control',
    duration: {
      start: '2:10.000',
      end: '2:40.403'
    },
    unit: 23,
  },

  {
    reference: 'we built the Tet our mission control',
    duration: {
      start: '2:40.000',
      end: '2:40.403'
    },
    unit: 23,
  },

  {
    reference: 'we built the Tet',
    duration: {
      start: '2:37.345',
      end: '2:38.500'
    },
    unit: 23,
  },
  {
    reference: 'we built the Tet our mission control',
    duration: {
      start: '2:30.000',
      end: '2:40.403'
    },
    unit: 23,
  }

];


console.log(getLongestByUnit(array))


function getLongestByUnit(array) {
  const by_unit = {};
  array.forEach(el => {

    let old = by_unit[el.unit]


    if (!old) {
      by_unit[el.unit] = el;
    } else if (el.reference == old.reference && (getSecondsDuration(el.duration.start, el.duration.end) > getSecondsDuration(old.duration.start, old.duration.end))) {
      by_unit[el.unit] = el;
    } else {
      by_unit[el.unit] = el;
    }

  });
  let result = Object.values(by_unit);
  return result;
}


function getSecondsDuration(start, end) {
  const milisecondsDiff = (hrsToSecs(end) * 1000) - (hrsToSecs(start) * 1000);
  return milisecondsDiff / 1000;
}

function hrsToSecs(hrs) {
  var b = hrs.split(':');
  return b.length > 2 ? b[0] * 3600 + b[1] * 60 + +b[2] : b[0] * 60 + +b[1];
}
```

So the desired output in the above array would be:

```
  [
      
      {
        reference: 'Tet our mission not here',
        duration: { start: '2:33.213', end: '2:35.871' },
        unit: 21,
      },
      
      {
        reference: 'Tet our mission',
        duration: { start: '2:33.213', end: '2:35.871' },
        unit: 22,
      },
      { // this one is the one with more duration 
        reference: 'we built the Tet our mission control',
        duration: { start: '2:10.000', end: '2:40.403' },
        unit: 23,
      },
      
      /* {  this is removed
        reference: 'we built the Tet our mission control',
        duration: { start: '2:40.000', end: '2:40.403' },
        unit: 23,
      }, */
      
      {
        reference: 'we built the Tet',
        duration: { start: '2:37.345', end: '2:38.500' },
        unit: 23,
      },
      /* { this should be removed too
        reference: 'we built the Tet our mission control',
        duration: { start: '2:30.000', end: '2:40.403' },
        unit: 23,
      } */
      
    ];
```

How would you do this?

Comment: Looks like all cases of your `if` lead to the element being overridden, so it doesn't matter which condition is or isn't matched. You will always end up with the last element of that id. My guess is that you want to remove the `else`.

Comment: With "same reference" in each unit I want the longer item,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter by two properties (unit and reference), you also need two layers when collecting.

As a tip, if you aggregate into an element outside a forEach (`by_unit` in your example), consider using a `for` instead, as it looks cleaner and happens to be faster, too.

I also added a function that compares the duration of two items by subtracting them from each other, as you would in a `sort()` function. This allows to check for first is smaller than second item (result less than zero), equal (result is zero) or larger (result larger zero).

For fun, I added a one-liner solution, ignore it if that's not your cup of tea.

```js
const array = [

  {
    reference: 'Tet our mission not here',
    duration: {
      start: '2:33.213',
      end: '2:35.871'
    },
    unit: 21,
  },

  {
    reference: 'Tet our mission',
    duration: {
      start: '2:33.213',
      end: '2:35.871'
    },
    unit: 22,
  },
  {
    reference: 'we built the Tet our mission control',
    duration: {
      start: '2:10.000',
      end: '2:40.403'
    },
    unit: 23,
  },

  {
    reference: 'we built the Tet our mission control',
    duration: {
      start: '2:40.000',
      end: '2:40.403'
    },
    unit: 23,
  },

  {
    reference: 'we built the Tet',
    duration: {
      start: '2:37.345',
      end: '2:38.500'
    },
    unit: 23,
  },
  {
    reference: 'we built the Tet our mission control',
    duration: {
      start: '2:30.000',
      end: '2:40.403'
    },
    unit: 23,
  }

];


console.log(getLongestByUnit(array))


function getLongestByUnit(array) {
  const byUnit = {};
  for(let el of array){
    const {reference, unit} = el
    if(!byUnit[unit]){
      byUnit[unit] = {}
    }
    const byReference = byUnit[unit]
    const max = byReference[reference]
    if(!max || compareDuration(el, max) > 0){
      byReference[reference] = el
    }
  }
  return Object.values(byUnit).flatMap(Object.values);
}

const longest = array.filter( (e1, i1) => !array.some( (e2,i2) => e1 !== e2 && e1.reference === e2.reference && (compareDuration(e1, e2) || i2 - i1) < 0))
console.log(longest)

function compareDuration(e1, e2){
  const diff1 = getSecondsDuration(e1.duration.start, e2.duration.end)
  const diff2 = getSecondsDuration(e1.duration.start, e2.duration.end)
  return diff1 - diff2
}

function getSecondsDuration(start, end) {
  const milisecondsDiff = (hrsToSecs(end) * 1000) - (hrsToSecs(start) * 1000);
  return milisecondsDiff / 1000;
}

function hrsToSecs(hrs) {
  var b = hrs.split(':');
  return b.length > 2 ? b[0] * 3600 + b[1] * 60 + +b[2] : b[0] * 60 + +b[1];
}
```